# d3.tsv() calls update function multiple times

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I just want to point out real quick that the code I have is really lengthy for what it does but I'm just trying to get things to work. I will clean it up/ shorten it if I'm able to solve this issue.

Anyways, my code first calls drawHistogram() to create the first histogram. Within draw histogram(), I have d3.tsv() and within d3.tsv(){ /* bunch of stuff in here */ }, I get the information for the bars and draw everything out. This is also where I call the update function, which is supposed to re-sort the data and re-draw the chart. HOWEVER, because my update function is inside the d3.tsv(), it ends up being called 47 times (the same length as my tsv). What would be a good way to prevent this? Should I be creating all my svg stuff (svg element, axis, bars, etc) and calling the graph update function outside of the d3.tsv() method? If so, how should I go about that?

Below is the jsfiddle link for the code. Once you click the X axis a few times, you'll notice in the console that a print statement is being repeated 47 times.

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6e7wd5hp/4/)

```
/* To keep this short, I've only include the frame of my code 
that I believe should be enough to show you the issue, but 
again, the whole code is on the jsfiddle. */

function drawHistogram() {
    // create svg and set x y domains

    d3.tsv(url, function (error, data) {
        if (error) throw error;

        /*
         * get values from tsv
         * scale the bars according to values
         * draw the bars
         */

    svg.append('line')
        .on('click', function () {
            .remove('svg');

            // since update is inside the d3.tsv, 
            // it ends up running too many times
            // can I somehow run all this outside of d3.tsv?
            update(data, 0, 'title');
        }
    });

    function update(data, type, title){

        // this will end up printing 47 times
        console.log("This is running")

        /* same as the drawHistogram()
         * recreate the svg element
         * I get and sort the values 
         * draw the bars, etc.
         */

        svg.append('line')
            .on('click', function () {
                .remove('svg');
                update(data, 0, 'title');
            }
        });
    };
};
```

Answer (score 1):

The way that you are using `d3.tsv()` is not what you intend.

`d3.tsv()` returns a promise. You chain a `then()` to the request, and the full array of data is returned as the argument to `then`'s callback:

```
d3.tsv('https://location/of/my/data')
  .then(function(dataset) {
    // dataset is an array
    svg.selectAll('line')
      .data(dataset)
      .enter()
      .append('line')
        .attr('d', d => buildLineUsingObj(d));
  });
```

**Note** that in the above example, **one** argument is being passed to the `tsv()` method.

You were passing **two** arguments to the `tsv()` method... the url, and a second function. If you have a look at the docs on [d3-fetch](https://github.com/d3/d3-fetch/blob/master/README.md#tsv), you will notice there is an optional `row` argument to `tsv()`. `row` is a mapping function that will run for *every item in your dataset*. It is used if you wish transform the data obtained by `tsv()` (perhaps to change formats, or make it easier to use in some way). This is the reason your update function is being called 47 times.

The following [example from the docs](https://github.com/d3/d3-fetch/blob/master/README.md#tsv) shows how to use the `row` function to map data:

```
d3.tsv("test.csv", function row(d) {
  return {
    year: new Date(+d.Year, 0, 1), // convert "Year" column to Date
    make: d.Make,
    model: d.Model,
    length: +d.Length // convert "Length" column to number
  };
}).then(function(data) {
  console.log(data);
});
```

Comment: So even if I changed the code to d3.tsv(url).then(function (data) { update() }; update still runs multiple times. My guess is that because it's looping through in function (data)? So should I be calling update() outside of d3.tsv? And if so, should I have an object array that saves these values so I can access them outside of d3.tsv()?